# A bounded function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove the following statement: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(xt)}{t} dt,$$ then $f$ is a bounded function. I start this problem by making the change of variables $u=xt$ and then I get $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi x}\frac{\sin u}{u} du.$$ I have no idea how to proceed from here. Thanks in advanced for any response.

Answer (score 4):

The oscillation of $\sin(u)$ is what is critical here, so integration by parts is useful.

$\int_1^x \frac{\sin(u)}{u}du = \frac{-\cos(u)}{u}\mid_1^x -\int_1^x \frac{\cos(u)}{u^2}du$, which is bounded by $\cos(1)+\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{1}{x}$.